# How to download the mysql_fix_privilege_tables.sql for windows platform

Tags: mysql

I tried to give privileges for users in MySQL Database. My MySQL server is hosted on the phpMyadmin.

**It get this error:**

> Your privilege table structure seems to be older than this MySQL
>   version! Please run the script mysql_fix_privilege_tables that should
>   be included in your MySQL server distribution to solve this problem!**

**MySQL Client and Server Version Details:**

- Server version: 4.1.14
- MySQL client version: 5.1.55

So I tried to download the script mysql_fix_privilege_tables.sql for reparing the table structure to 5.1.55. but I cannot find the script for Windows.

I also want to know the steps for executing the script on phpMyAdmin.

Could anyone help me to find solutions for upgrading my MySQL server?

Comment: That script is platform independent. You should be able to run it on your OS

Comment: Could you give that script for Repairing the MySQL server version from 4.1.14 to 5.1.55 and steps for how to execute that script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the [docs](http://mirror.metrocast.net/mysql/doc/refman/4.1/en/mysql-fix-privilege-tables.html):

What to do:

> On Windows systems, there isn't an easy way to update the system tables until MySQL 4.0.15. From version 4.0.15 on, MySQL distributions include a mysql_fix_privilege_tables.sql SQL script that you can run using the mysql client. For example, if your MySQL installation is located at C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 4.1, the commands look like this:

```
C:\> cd "C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 4.1"
C:\> bin\mysql -u root -p mysql
mysql> SOURCE scripts/mysql_fix_privilege_tables.sql
```

The mysql command will prompt you for the root password; enter it when prompted.

> If your installation is located in some other directory, adjust the path names appropriately.
>
> As with the Unix procedure, you might see some Duplicate column name warnings as mysql processes the statements in the mysql_fix_privilege_tables.sql script; you can ignore them.

After running the script, stop the server and restart it.

Hope this is clear enough.

I'd advise dumping all your databases and importing them into a new mysql 5.6 version.

**Note**:
If you're connecting to phpMyAdmin with a root account, you can just go to the "SQL" tab and paste the contents of that script in the textarea and click "Go" (instead of running it from a console)

Comment: Hi Alex,Could you give that script suitable for my version. Thanks.

Comment: This seems to be the right link: https://github.com/HiSPARC/station-software/blob/master/user/mysql/share/mysql_fix_privilege_tables.sql

Comment: Hi Alex,while running this script i'm getting the following error: ** #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '\'\';
set storage_engine=myisam;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS db (   Host char' at line 1** . i'm confused on storage engine myisam and Innodb ,which is default one .i think this error occurs because of myisam  .how to rectify this error .

Comment: I'm betting you ran that from phpMyadmin. it shouldn't be `'\'\ , but `''` (not escaped). This is how phpMyAdmin escapes all input . Try replacing single quotes `'` with double-quotes `"`. Or perhaps another option is to import the  `sql` (using the "import" button)

Comment: Also, for internal dbs and tables, you don't need to worry on which engine it uses. Mysql will definitely use the right one